# How to remove class from body if condition is not met?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm working with an if statement to show an alert message depending on certain conditions.

Under the second condition `New Article` I want a specific css class to be added `(show-banner-alert)`. I am able to get the css added but its now affecting the conditions following it.

I've tried adding a `$("body").removeClass` and adding a new class with different properties but I am unable to get rid of the first-class successfully.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).on("load", function(e) {
  $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');

  if (document.cookie.includes("isDismissed=true")) {
    document.body.classList.add("alert.container");
  } else if ("@pageTitle" === ("New Article") !== "-1") {
    document.body.classList.add("show-banner-alert");
  } else if ("@pageTitle".indexOf("Test") !== "-1") {
    $("body").removeClass("show-banner-alert").addClass("show-alert");
  } else if ("@pageTitle".indexOf("New Home") !== "-1") {
    document.body.classList.add("show-alert");
  } 
});
```

Comment: You forgot a `)` here: `$("body").removeClass("show-banner-alert".addClass("show-alert");`

Comment: May be this is the problem? The unclosed bracket in your chaining? $("body").removeClass("show-banner-alert").addClass("show-alert");

Comment: I closed the `)` but the second condition is still getting the css property `show-banner-alert` instead of `show-alert`

Comment: You've got a peculiar mix of jQuery and straight DOM there... I'd pick one and stick with it so that later developers are not confused. `document.body.classList.remove("show-banner-alert"); document.body.classList.add("show-alert");` The second condition doesn't make any sense; the string "New Article" will never equal the string "-1"...

Comment: You only use `!== -1` when you're using `.indexOf()`. If you want to do an exact match, just write `if ("@pageTitle" == "New Article")`

Comment: I agree about not mxing DOM and jQuery. Write `$("body").addClass("show-banner-alert");`

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to have a class with `.` in its name, since `.` is the prefix use for classes in CSS.

Answer (score -1):

first :
none of the conditions are correct.
all the if conditions are going to give you a correct answer ( true ).
second : 
try either using jquery or using vanilla js for dom manipulation. ( I'd recommend jquery).